# php - shortest function return

Tags: php

Hi 
Is there any shorter way for a function to return true if parameter = 10 ?
I have tried searching on the internet but I could not find any answers - most probably because I am not aware of the keywords to search for.

What I have done is

```
function isTen($a) {
if ($a == 10) return true;
return false
}
```

Is this the shortest code one can get to in PHP ? 
If there is somewhere to read up on this.. please let me know.  Right now I feel like I'm looking for a needle in a haystack :(

Comment: Do you mean "return ($a == 10)" ?;

Comment: can u go any shorter than this ?

Comment: Yes, please don't use functions for something so trivial!

Comment: read the comments i left for jondavidjohn. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function isTen($a) {
    return ($a == 10);
}
```

***BUT!*** why would you make a function for this, when you could just check it in-line?

Comment: Its just an example... I was wondering if theres anyway we could just do a return on the function parameter line.. I guess not  =\

Comment: Well, PHP is not whitespace dependant, so you could write it like `function isTen($a) { return ($a == 10); }` all on one line.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `$a === 10` is already a boolean.
Therefore, you can just return it:

```
return $a === 10;
```

[Note that you should be using `===`, which checks for identity instead of equivalence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Unless $a comes from some text that contains '10'?

Comment: I don't think we know enough about his intended use to recommend `===` over `==` , technically his concern is length, so `==` would be one character shorter. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite it like this, the result is implicitly a boolean:

```
function isTen($a) {
   return ($a == 10);
}
```

If "short" is of absolute concern, leave out even the spaces and brackets. Yes, definitely brackets.

```
function isTen($a){return $a==10;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator

```
$isTen = ($a == 10) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Comment: If it's expected to be an int, **write `? 1 : 0`!**  Then, it won't be very wrong.

Comment: HES LOOKING FOR A BOOLEAN RETURN: "any shorter way for a function to return true"

Comment: Yeah, which is "return $a == 10;", and not that ternary operator mess. In fact, just don't ever use the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

personally i think its a waste of  time creating a function specifically to check for a single value, you shuold do something like so:

```
function is($value,$check,$strict = false)
{
    if($strict === true)
    {
        return $value === $check;
    }

    return $value == $check;
}
```

this way you can use it for other things aswell, such as:

```
is(true,true,true); //true
is(false,false,true); //
is(10,11,true); //false
is(10,10,true); //true
is(10,10); //true
is($myvar,10); //if $myVar is 10 then true;
```